# What's the order of PersistentProperty instances are iterated over for a Spring Data PersistentEntity?

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-commons

What is the access order of `PersistentProperty`s when iterating over them? Is it the same as in the definition of `PersistentEntity`, or is it random? I couldn't find any information about this in [the Javadoc of Spring Data](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mapping/PersistentEntity.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fundamentally, the ultimate source of the properties created is Java's `Class.getDeclaredFields()` which doesn't guarantee any particular order. The high-level property creation algorithm can be found in [`AbstractMappingContext`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/blob/03a6a84bf97b5cfcf5bd48a0f76421aca3bd3fbd/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/mapping/context/AbstractMappingContext.java#L395-L440) (`ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(…)` making the connection).

I've filed and fixed [a ticket](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/issues/2814) in Spring Data Commons to clarify this in the Javadoc.